# Flutter - access camera storage directory

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I need to add text to images as soon as they are captured. For this, I need access the image(directory where the camera saves them by default). The app asks for the permission fine.

```
  Future<void> _initializePhotoWatcher() async {

if (await Permission.storage.isGranted) {
  // This gets the primary external storage directory, which may not directly be accessible in Android 10+
  Directory? externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  String cameraPath =
      '${externalDir?.path}/DCIM/Camera'; // This is a common path, but might vary
  final dir = Directory(cameraPath);

  if (await dir.exists()) {
    final watcher = DirectoryWatcher(cameraPath);
    watcher.events.listen((event) async {
      if (event.type == ChangeType.ADD) {
        final file = File(event.path);
        if (await file.exists()) {
          _addStampToPhoto(file);
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    print("Camera directory does not exist or is not accessible");
  }
} else {
  print("Need access to storage.");
}
}
```

This code always returns the line "Camera directory does not exist or is not accessible", meaning the camera location (image) cannot be accessed. How do I access the image and add text to it? Does this require native code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the Problem I see in your code, is that Path_Providers getExternalStorageDirectory returns the App's directory. So for example: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.foo.foo/files'. So by adding /DCIM/Camera to that Path you try to access a (probably) not existing dictionary. For Android you can just use:

```
String cameraPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/";
final dir = Directory(cameraPath);
```

This code should work as intended for Android, although I don't really know anything about iOS, so I can not help you there sorry...